# Why is the design criteria for ConcurrentModificationException chosen only to be structural modification

Tags: java, collections, concurrentmodification, design-decisions

I do understand that ConcurrentModificationExcpetion is thrown whenever there is a structural modification of the underlying collection after an iterator has been created. This seems to be a design decision.

I was wondering why update, through set() methods, is not considered for CME? Ultimately, the collection is getting updated and if iterator is created, traversal could still result in inconsistent results.

Comment: With add and remove operations you can have elements that are accidentially skipped or traversed despite being gone or seen twice, which is definitely incorrect and unpredictable. With set that can't happen, you do see the latest value and from the point of view of the iteration nothing is inherently broken

Comment: adding/removing elements changes the size of collection whereas update does not change the size. If you are traversing using iterator for every next() call, it also call for checkForModifcation() on same AbstractList;

Comment: You mean having an `Iterator<String>` for a `List<String> list` doesn't throw a CME if an element in `list` gets updated? But what does mean updated? Should a CME be thrown if `list.get(0).equals("1")` and `list.set(1, "1")` is called? The strings are equal but might be not the same (`!=`). Is equality the criteria to decide whether an element has been updated? By throwing a CME only on structural changes this question is not a concern of `Iterator`. This could be a reason.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know the exact reasons for the design decision unless you were actually involved in making them.

I surmise that the reason might be that the iterator is designed to iterate the *collection*, rather than the *values in the collection*.

In other words, the iterator is like a "pointer" which will just be moved to point to each "space" in the collection in turn. By knowing something about the "shape" of the collection when the iterator is constructed, you know how to move the pointer to point to the next space in the collection.

If the value stored in a space changes, it doesn't really matter: that space and all other spaces in the collection are left unchanged.

However, if you change the shape of the collection via a structural modification, you've basically invalidated any assumptions that you have about where that pointer is pointing; short of doing something very clever, you may as well just give up and throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

> Ultimately, the collection is getting updated and if iterator is created, traversal could still result in inconsistent results.

Actually, I think that the reason is that the `set` operations *won't* lead to inconsistent results.  The code iterating the collection will either see the results of the `set` call's modification ... or not ... in a highly predictable fashion.  And the code is guaranteed to still see each other element of the collection (i.e. apart from the one that you "set") exactly once.

By contrast, structural modifications on typical non-concurrent collections can cause the collection entries / elements to move around.  For example:

- An insertion or deletion in an `ArrayList` causes the elements in the backing array to change position.
- An insertion in a `HashMap` or `HashSet` can cause resizing which causes the hash chains to be reconstructed.

In both cases, the structural modification can lead to elements being skipped, or seen more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Please find my comments to your assumptions below.

> I do understand that `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown whenever there is a structural modification of the underlying collection after an iterator has been created.

Not exactly. The `ConcurrentModificationException` is actually thrown when the iterator attempts to fetch the next value and there has been a structural change in the underlying collection. (I want to stress that the `ConcurrentModificationException` is not thrown when invoking i.e. `add` or `remove` on the underlying collection).

Then, concerning your last assumption:

> Ultimately, the collection is getting updated and if iterator is created, traversal could still result in inconsistent results.

I don't think this is correct. How could traversal still result in inconsistent results? If i.e. you modify the value at the i-th position of a list, you'll immediately see this change. The list is in fact modified, but not *structurally* modified. Only the value at the i-th position changes, but not the structure of the list (i.e. `ArrayList`'s underlying array won't incur the risk of being resized, `LinkedList` won't allocate a new node, etc).

Finally, with regard to this sentence:

> This seems to be a design decision.

Absolutely. It is 100% a design decision, and while I haven't been part of it, I'm certain that it has been driven by the aim of avoiding inconsistencies when traversing the underlying collection. Better than ending up with unexpected or inconsistent data, throw an exception as early as possible and let the user know.

However, the docs also mention that *fail-fast* iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a **best-effort** basis.

For example, consider the following code:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    try {
        Integer next = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("iterator.next() = " + next);

        System.out.println("BEFORE remove: " + list);
        list.remove(0);
        System.out.println("AFTER remove: " + list);

    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {

        System.out.println("CME thrown, ending abnormally...");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Here we are attempting to remove the first element of the list while iterating over it. Upon execution, you'll see the following output:

```
iterator.next() = 1
BEFORE remove: [1, 2, 3]
AFTER remove: [2, 3]
CME thrown, ending abnormally...
```

This is the expected behavior. A `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when the iterator attempts to fetch an element from the list for the second time. This is because the implementation detects that a structural change has been made since the iterator was created. Thus, `iterator.next()` throws a CME.

However, as *fail-fast* iterators are not guaranteed to always throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but to do it only on a best-effort basis, there's a way to trick the implementation. Consider the code below, which is a modified version of the previous snippet (if you execute it, be warned that it will take some time until it finishes):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

int structuralChanges = 0;

Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    try {
        Integer next = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("iterator.next() = " + next);

        System.out.println("BEFORE remove: " + list);
        list.remove(0);
        System.out.println("AFTER remove: " + list);
        structuralChanges++;

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            structuralChanges++;
            list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            structuralChanges++;
        }
        list.add(0);
        structuralChanges++;

        System.out.println("Structural changes so far = " + structuralChanges);

    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {

        System.out.println("CME NEVER thrown, so you won't see this message");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

System.out.println("AFTER everything: " + list);
System.out.println("Program ending normally");
```

Here we are again removing the first element of the list while iterating it, but before the iterator fetches the next element, we're doing millions of structural modifications. In fact, we are doing `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1` structural modifications, if we consider all the `list.add(i)` and `list.remove(list.size() - 1)` calls inside the `for` loop, along with the `list.add(0)` call immediately after the `for` loop.

Additionally, we're keeping track of all structural modifications via the `structuralChanges` variable, which is incremented immediately after each structural modification.

Upon execution of the code above, you'll see the following output:

```
iterator.next() = 1
BEFORE remove: [1, 2, 3]
AFTER remove: [2, 3]
Structural changes so far = 0
iterator.next() = 3
BEFORE remove: [2, 3, 0]
AFTER remove: [3, 0]
Structural changes so far = 0
iterator.next() = 0
BEFORE remove: [3, 0, 0]
AFTER remove: [0, 0]
Structural changes so far = 0
AFTER everything: [0, 0, 0]
Program ending normally
```

As the output shows, no `ConcurrentModificationException` has been thrown.

Besides, after all structural modifications have been made, the value of the `structuralChanges` variable ends up being `0`. This is because it is a variable of type `int` and it is overflowing and reaching `0` again, after being incremented `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 2` times (`Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1` times due to our artificial `for` loop and subsequent increment, plus `1` due to the `list.remove(0)` call of the original code).

Then, after all these `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 2` structural modifications, when we call `iterator.next()` on the following iteration of the `while` loop, no `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown, ever. We've tricked the implementation, so we can now see what happens to the data internally. (Internally, the implementation keeps track of the structural modifications by keeping an `int` count, as I've done with my `structuralChanges` variable).

Comment: I always keep wondering why can't I think of such answers. Not my forte, I guess. And I love it when Java programs are written to cheat the implementation. Design decision? Who cares? We can still cheat it.

Comment: @Sara Cheating this particular design decision has been fun. But it wouldn't be very practical, I think. It took a while running on my laptop. I've only written it to show that your code should never rely on `ConcurrentModificationException` being thrown. (I know you haven't asked about that, but I think it's related). I think the output shows that behavior of the iterator is somewhat unexpected. The first time it returns `1`, which is correct, 2nd time it returns `3`, but I would have expected it to return `2`, despite the first element of the list has been removed. 3rd time `3`instead of `0`